# Elements getting moved above soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-designer

My Problem is, if the soft Keyboard Pops up, every element on my activity gets moved up. Except for my two TextViews on top of the activity.

[Softkeyboard_off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFP1h.png)
[Softkeyboard_on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPqxv.png)

I was serching for a solution on the Web but didn't find anything that worked for me. 
Does somone know how to Change this?

***activity.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/RelativeLayout"
tools:context=".Activity_booking_bookings">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/oper_name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/wo_no"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/reject_code"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/qty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ring"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/pos"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Path"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/table2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableRow"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TableLayout

    android:id="@+id/table2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_home"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fa_btn_plus"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/m_wo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/s_wo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/op"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/prod"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/blank"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/good"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/scrap"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="@string/home"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_next2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:onClick="onClick_next_activity3"
    android:text="@string/next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:onClick="onClick_back_MainActivity"
    android:text="@string/back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fa_btn_plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="onClickPlus"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/table2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this line in your activity in Manifest file

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Check the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for more info.

**OR**

Try to implement the below code in your Activity class

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer the second one workes perfectly as i wanted.